# SMTP modules in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to write an email using python's smtplib module. Here is my code as well as the error displayed below. Thank you!

```
import smtplib

my_email = 'xxxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com'
password = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
# I hid my email and password here

with smtplib.SMTP('outlook.office365.com') as connection:
    connection.starttls()
    connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
    connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs=my_email, msg='helloworld')
```

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/guanhongjiang/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Birthday Wisher (Day 32) start/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/guanhongjiang/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Birthday Wisher (Day 32) start/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP('outlook.office365.com') as connection:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 845, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 833, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Comment: TLS SMTP is not done on the default port 25.  You should try port 587.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. May I ask what this port is?

Comment: Google could tell you quicker.  587 is the standard port for SMTP over TLS.  465 was used for a while, but 587 is the official one.